# Assistant app keeps replying with "What was that again?"

Tags: actions-on-google

My team recently created a Google Assistant app on the "Actions on Google" platform.

The app uses actions defined on Dialogflow.com and some backend functions running on Firebase.

Today the app stopped working. When launching the app in the Simulator using ("Talk to ") the app starts up and immediately responds with "What was that again?", even before any voice commands were given.

Any idea how this can be debugged?

Comment: It might be a bug in the simulator. Can you click the test button again? Does it work as expected in the Dialogflow simulator?

Answer (score 2):

One good thing to do is to have the Fallback Intent do fulfillment with your webhook. This will send everything, including failed messages, to you and might give you some idea what it thinks it is hearing.

You can also look at the [Google Activity](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity) history and filter by the "Voice & Audio" and "Assistant" products. This will let you hear exactly what took place at each step of the conversation and how Google interpreted it.